# Group by sum with running calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df as

```
Sales | Users |   DT
40000    234     1/4/2018
500      100     1/23/2018
4000     555     2/4/2018
234      1000    6/4/2018
1000     2000    6/14/2018
50000    1200    9/12/2018
40000    234     1/14/2019
500      100     2/23/2019
2145     555     2/26/2019
344      1000    6/14/2019
1234     1233    6/21/2019
432      5000     11/12/2019
```

Is there method to group-by to both sum up sales by yr and also create a rolling total of users as my users column is composed of both new users, and users from previous date so basically group by year, sum sales, and then sum users from next date - prev date users

Thank you

Comment: Hi there, I almost got it, the only thing I couldn't understand very well is " sum from users from next date - prev date.  Since values of Users in the example are the same, 2018 would have an total of Users (sum) of 5089 and the difference between 2019 and 2018 would be zero. Could you maybe give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: Hi, I just randomly made up numbers for this example! I changed the above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Sales": [40000, 500, 4000, 234, 1000, 50000, 40000, 500, 2145, 344, 1234, 432],
        "Users": [234, 100, 555, 1000, 2000, 1200, 234, 100, 555, 1000, 1233, 5000],
        "DT": ["1/4/2018", "1/23/2018", "2/4/2018", "6/4/2018", "6/14/2018", "9/12/2018", "1/14/2019", "2/23/2019", "2/26/2019", "6/14/2019", "6/21/2019", "11/12/2019"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```py
df["DT"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT"]).dt.year

df = (
    df.groupby("DT")
    .agg(sum)
    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(Users=df_["Users"].cumsum()))
    .reset_index()
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
     DT  Sales  Users
0  2018  95734   5089
1  2019  44655  13211
```